# Transpose Diagonal to row in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I've tried to find a formula that would return the diagonal of an array `A1:D4` as follows:

```
A1 B2 C3 D4
```

I found this one, which returns a column, but I can't find out how to order the values in a row instead.

```
=INDEX(A1:D1,,ROWS($1:1))
```

(paste in the columns below)

A `TRANSPOSE` on the result would of course do the trick, but I'd appreciate something slightly more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the exact range you mentioned (A1:D4) then this should work

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(IF(ROW(A1:D4)=COLUMN(A1:D4), A1:D4,),,ROWS(A1:A4))))
```

(No need to fill down.)

[image: Example 1:]

If you want to get the diagonal values of any range (here: B11:E14), try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(IF(ROW(B11:E14)-ROW(B11)+1=COLUMN(B11:E11)-COLUMN(B11)+1, B11:E14,),,ROWS(B11:B14))))
```

[image: Example 2:]

Answer (score 0):

How about this, then as you pull it across it will go down the diagonal

```
=index($A$1:$D$4,columns($A1:A1),columns($A1:A1))
```

or the equivalent of your original formula would be

```
=index(A1:A4,COLUMNS($A1:A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using undocumented [`FLATTEN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505164/how-can-i-generate-an-array-of-numbers-between-multiple-ranges-defined-in-separa/61508461?noredirect=1#comment108812422_61508461) life saving function:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
    FLATTEN(
      ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(COLUMN(A1:D4) = ROW(A1:D4), A1:D4, "")
      )
    ),
    "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",
    0
  )
)
```

[image]

And if the range is not at the top left corner:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
    FLATTEN(
      ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
          COLUMN(F15:I18) - COLUMN(INDEX(F15:I18, 1, 1)) + 1 = ROW(F15:I18) - ROW(INDEX(F15:I18, 1, 1)) + 1,
            F15:I18,
            ""
        )
      )
    ),
    "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",
    0
  )
)
```

Intentionally used `INDEX(F15:I18, 1, 1)` instead of just `F15` to have only the range `F15:I18` (e.g. it could be a named range) as a parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

get all diagonals:

∕

`=SORT({ FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:E9) + COLUMN(A5:E9))), FLATTEN(A5:E9) })`

∖

`=SORT({ FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:E9) - COLUMN(A5:E9))), FLATTEN(A5:E9) })`

Source: https://t.me/google_spreadsheets_chat/159476