# Combine column cell interchangeably in one column

Tags: google-sheets, combinations, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Let us assume we have the following tow columns :

**column 1**

```
1
3
5
```

**column 2**

```
2
4
6
```

**the result column**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and in case the two columns are not equal in size, the combined result should be without empty cells at the end!

Comment: Copy-paste-sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=FLATTEN(A1:B)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, A1:B), "♦"))
```

[image]

---

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A1:B="",,"♦"&A1:B)),,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Any documentation or source for flatten?

Comment: @TheMaster nope, its a hidden function

Comment: How did you figure it out?

Comment: @TheMaster first time heard it few months ago from MattKing and 2 days ago he shared a story about it in comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61566901/5632629

Comment: Thanks for sharing.