# Formula to find max & min of string if sort alphabetical

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

if I have a list of string like '0401 A', '0319 B' '0801 C' and they appears in different columns and rows in an excel sheet, what is the formula to get the max & min of these strings. In this case, max and min would be '0801 C' and '0319 B' if its sorted alphabetically. INDEX-MATCH doesn't seems to work since the strings are in multiple rows and columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this for Maximum:

```
=SORTN(FLATTEN(A:C), 1, 0, 1, False)
```

and this for Minimum:

```
=SORTN(FLATTEN(A:C), 1, 0, 1, True)
```

I've just learned about `FLATTEN`: it is native but undocumented function in Google Sheets, which will make a 2D-range into a column - very useful stuff. I [learned about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505164/how-can-i-generate-an-array-of-numbers-between-multiple-ranges-defined-in-separa/61508461?noredirect=1#comment108812422_61508461) recently from @MattKing here on SO.

[image]

`A:C` could also be a bit pre-filtered of empty cells wtih `FILTER(A:C, (A:A <> "") + (B:B <> "") + (C:C <> ""))` or something else.

Comment: thanks for sharing.  The link in your answer just points to the image in this post.  Could you make it point to the post you're referring to?

Comment: @MattKing fixed that. Thanks again! `FLATTEN` is recently my favorite hammer.

Comment: you and I are gonna spread it across the land.  Hopefully they don't scrap it and we end up leaving a huge swath of broken sheets in our wake.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised there isn't a function like "MAX" in numerical values for string.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data housed in `A5`, `B2` and `C3`

In Max value result `F1`, enter formula :

```
=INDEX(T(INDIRECT({"B2","C3","A5"})),MATCH(MAX(0+LEFT(T(INDIRECT({"B2","C3","A5"})),4)),0+LEFT(T(INDIRECT({"B2","C3","A5"})),4),0))
```

In Min value result `F2`, enter formula :

```
=INDEX(T(INDIRECT({"B2","C3","A5"})),MATCH(MIN(0+LEFT(T(INDIRECT({"B2","C3","A5"})),4)),0+LEFT(T(INDIRECT({"B2","C3","A5"})),4),0))
```

[image]

Comment: I have way more values than 3 cells. hard code the location does not work

Answer (score 0):

if each column contains only one value:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C);;9^9))); 1; 0; 1; 0))

=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C);;9^9))); 1; 0; 1; 1))
```

if there are multiple values in each column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A:C="";;"♦"&A:C));;9^9));;9^9); "♦"))); 1; 0; 1; 0))

=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A:C="";;"♦"&A:C));;9^9));;9^9); "♦"))); 1; 0; 1; 1))
```