# Google Sheets Cartesian product with transposed columns

Tags: google-sheets

Is there recommended ways to convert table in `A2:F6` to `H2:K10`?

Thanks.

[image]

Here is the sample Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOZVMIRvM_9lhvAflhQtA9H6KOpfHycPo5qgF1y-GzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471

Comment: A few years ago I thought my 5 lines formulas were big...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relatively simple way to do than using [`FLATTEN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505164/how-can-i-generate-an-array-of-numbers-between-multiple-ranges-defined-in-separa/61508461?noredirect=1#comment108812422_61508461):

```
={
  ARRAYFORMULA(A1:C1), "Product";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    VLOOKUP(
      FILTER(
        FLATTEN(ROW(D2:F) + 0 * ISBLANK(D2:F)),
        FLATTEN(D2:F <> "")
      ),
      FILTER(
        {ROW(A2:A), A2:C},
        A2:A <> ""
      ),
      {2, 3, 4},
      0
    )
  ),
  FILTER(
    FLATTEN(D2:F),
    FLATTEN(D2:F <> "")
  )
}
```

[image]

Not sure why `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(D2:F))` gives row wise row numbers and not a 2d matrix with the row numbers. Could've remove `0 * ISBLANK(D2:F)` otherwise...

Comment: This solution is more complex but from my testing it is very fast. Thanks

Comment: @yoonghm It also will save you a lot of trouble if you have a lot of product columns.

Comment: What is meaning of `ROW(D2:F) + 0 * ISBLANK(D2:F))`?

Comment: @yoonghm Forcing `ARRAYFORMULA` to return a 2d range and not just a column. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432752/how-to-get-a-matrix-with-the-row-numbers-for-every-cell-of-the-original-matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following query formula:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({A:D;A2:C,E2:E;A2:C,F2:F},"where Col1 is not null order by Col1"), "where Col4 is not null")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: `=QUERY({A:D; A2:C, E2:E; A2:C, F2:F}, "where Col1 is not null and Col4 is not null order by Col1")`?

Comment: @kishkin In this case, sure, that too. :)

Comment: These are elegant and reusable solution in many places. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity. Why did you finally accept a more complicated formula? Is there something not working right with this one?

Comment: If possible, I will tick both as solution.  I tried both solution just now, solution from @kishkin is very fast.  My original data has 13 such columns and your solution is elegant. Let me check on bigger data.

Comment: @marikamitsos if the number of product columns is greater than 24, your formula will become longer than mine due to manual construction of the `QUERY`s 1st parameter. With `FLATTEN` solution only `D2:F` will change to a wider range like `D2:Z`.