# How to get a matrix with the row numbers for every cell of the original matrix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Stumbled upon a strange behavior. This formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW($A$1:$E$5))
```

Returns a 5 element column with the row numbers from 1 to 5. I thought that `ARRAYFORMULA` would iterate through every cell in the range specified and execute the `ROW()` on it - resulting in a new range of the same size (5 columns, 5 rows), but with the row numbers in cells.

For example `=ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK($A$1:$E$5))` returns a 5 on 5 range.

[image]

I found a way to force the desired behavior (see the answer below), but is there a better way? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lot of people use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COLUMN(A1:E5),ROW(A1:E5)))
```

There are a lot of ways to do it, but almost all will involve using two refs.

This is about as small as I could get it.  Depends on what your inputs look like as to whether this would make sense to use.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,5,0,0)+SEQUENCE(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

not rly much to say here just that `ROW` and `COLUMN` are only one dimensional. in other words, `ROW` will work only with one single column and `COLUMN` will work only with one single row - no matter that you feed it with range **A1:Z** or **A1:A**

as mentioned you can use MattKing's `SEQUENCE` to generate the matrix

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A5)*COLUMN(A:E)^0)
```

[image]

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(ROW(A1:A5)*COLUMN(A:E)^0)
```

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(ROW(A1:A5)*{1,1,1,1,1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for you, man:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW($A$1:$E$5) + 0 * ISBLANK(A1:E5))
```

`0 * ISBLANK(A1:E5)` part is there just to force the desired behavior without modifying (see that multiplication by `0`?) the values you need.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome! But I advise you to wait for a better solution.